# Im coding a console application, but im having trouble. None of my code is showing up in the output window

Tags: c#

The only thing showing up is "press enter to continue". Ive tried switching the debug settings around but nothing is working. None of my writeline codes are outputting anything. The language is c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("enter the values of sales");

        int sales;
        int commission = new int();

        String value = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(value, out sales))



            if (sales < 100000)

                commission = 5;

            else if (sales >= 100000 && sales <= 250000)

                commission = 6;

            else if (sales >= 250000)

                commission = 7;

            else
            {

                Console.Write("sales");

                Console.WriteLine(sales);

                sum = sum + ((sales / 100) * (commission));

                i--;
                return;




            }

        else

        {
            Console.WriteLine("total of all commissions");

            Console.Write(sum);
            return;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine etc. are indeed correct ways to output something to the console window, so they should produce output if and when executed.

What you SHOULDN'T be seeing is a message "press enter to continue" - because that simply isn't in the code you posted, and is no default behaviour of console applications either.

Which leads me to the conclusion that your code isn't executed at all. You could easily test this by setting a breakpoint at the beginning of your code, and see if that breakpoint is reached at all (visual studio would stop and wait for you to click on continue when reaching a breakpoint).

Are you sure that A) you are actually compiling & launching your application from visual studio (not just opening some .exe from the explorer), and B) that your code is placed in your application's main method? By default, that would be ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // right in here!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your conditions, your code will never reach the `Console.Write("sales")` because you test all possible values of `sales` before the `else` cause.

Answer (score 0):

The only two places it has any printing, it's when:

1. TryParse **worked**: Printing doesn't work.
2. TryParse **didn't worked**: Printing OK.

We can examine and see that #1 printing appears at the `else` which is completely dependent upon `sales` value.

When we examine the **conditions before the **else**, we can see they are handling the entire range of possible numbers.

- (sales < 100000)
- (sales >= 100000 && sales <= 250000)
- (sales >= 250000)
- Else - Never can be reached.

Thus, you should rethink which operations goes when, and if the else is even need, and if it does, in which range it should apply.

**Note:** You have twice the handling on "250000" 2nd and 3rd conditions, but because 2nd condition comes first, it will only apply for it, thus the 3rd condition is redundant `=` and should be removed. (Or move the equality for the 3rd condition.)